# How to add a column with values 1 to len(df) to a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The index that I have in the dataframe (with 30 rows) is of the form:

```
Int64Index([171, 174, 173, 172, 199, …, 175, 200])
```

The index is not strictly increasing because the data frame is the output of a sort().

I want to add a column which is the series:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, …, 30]
```

How should I go about doing that?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

How about this:

```
from pandas import *

idx = Int64Index([171, 174, 173])
df = DataFrame(index = idx, data =([1,2,3]))
print df
```

It gives me:

```
     0
171  1
174  2
173  3
```

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Almost. So, in sum, I need to create another data frame which contains the rank/position of the row. And then, I need to join these.

Comment: Yes you combine add this df to your existing dataframe by using df.combine_first(df2)

Answer (score 174):

How about:

```
df['new_col'] = range(1, len(df) + 1)
```

Alternatively if you want the index to be the ranks and store the original index as a column:

```
df = df.reset_index()
```

Comment: This answer got me halfway to where I wanted since I already had an index that I wanted replaced. In such a case you can complement with:
 `df = df.reset_index(drop=True)`

Comment: Using `np.arange` instead of native `range`, like `df['new_col'] = np.arange(1, df.shape[0] + 1)` should speed up the runtime, especially when dealing with large datasets.

Answer (score 109):

I stumbled on this question while trying to do the same thing (I think). Here is how I did it:

```
df['index_col'] = df.index
```

You can then sort on the new index column, if you like.

Comment: No, that would be unsorted.

Comment: more dynamic `df[df.index.name] = df.index`

Answer (score 9):

The way to do that would be this:

Resetting the index:

```
df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
```

Sorting an index:

```
df.sort_index(inplace=True)
```

Setting a new index from a column:

```
df.set_index('column_name', inplace=True)
```

Setting a new index from a range:

```
df.index = range(1, 31, 1) #a range starting at one ending at 30 with a stepsize of 1.
```

Sorting a dataframe based on column value:

```
df.sort_values(by='column_name', inplace=True)
```

Reassigning variables works as-well:

```
df=df.reset_index(drop=True)
df=df.sort_index()
df=df.set_index('column_name')
df.index = range(1, 31, 1) #a range starting at one ending at 30 with a stepsize of 1.
df=df.sort_values(by='column_name')
```

Comment: I don't think you answered: `I want to add a column which is the [sort order] series` ie set a column to the index.